# PHP Send multiple data with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am working with jQuery and I've got some problem to pass more than one data selected from "Forms.html" then , by using jQuery "ajax.js", try to send to "ajaxServer.php". Then, the  "ajaxServer.php", based on the data received, will execute a certain function. But I observed that I am just able to receive one value at "ajaxServer.php" and the other always give me the error: "undefined index".

Does anyone has a tip to give me? It is possible to send multiple data like this and then choose the function what will be called in "ajaxServer.php"?

**Forms.html**

```
  <html>
      <body>
                <form id = "form1" > 
                                <div>
                                  <input type="hidden"  id="item1_form1" value="Abraham"> 
                                  <input type="hidden"  id="item2_form1" value="10">
                                  <input type="submit" class="button1" id="button_send" name="ping_spn" value="Send">

                                </div>
                             </form> 


                    <form id = "form2">
                            <div>
                                 <input type="hidden"  id="item1_form2" value="Bill"> 
                                 <input type="hidden"  id="item2_form2" value="20">
                                <input type="submit" class="button1" id="button_send2" name="button_send2" value="Send2">

                            </div>
                        </form>


                        <p id="Result"> <p>

       </body>
    </html>
```

**ajax.js**

```
$('#form1').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajaxServer.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
                'info_form1': $('#item1_form1').val(),
                'info_form2': $('#item2_form1').val()
            }
        }).done(function(data){

             $('#result').html(data);


        });

    });

    $('#form2').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajaxServer.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
                'info_form1': $('#item1_form2').val(),
                'info_form2': $('#item2_form2').val()
            }
        }).done(function(data){

             $('#result').html(data);


        });

    });
```

**ajaxServer.php**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["item1_form1"])){


        $a=$_POST["item1_form1"];
        $b= $_POST["item2_form1"];

       function toForm1($a,$b);
    }   

if(isset($_POST["item1_form2"])){


        $a= $_POST["item1_form2"];
        $b= $_POST["item2_form2"];
        function fromForm2($a,$b);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        dt = new FormData();
        dt.append( 'info_form1', $('#form1').serializeArray());
        dt.append( 'info_form2', $('#form2').serializeArray());

        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajaxServer.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: dt
        }).done(function(data){

             $('#result').html(data);


        });

    });
```